How to automate Mouse event in Android
I am currently testing some android applications and inside the app have some contextual menu only triggered by mouse right click.
Do we have any method or solution to automatically trigger that menu without plug in a real mouse and do it manually
I have tried scrcpy to interact with it using my mouse plug into my computer, but that solution still require me to do it manually
